# Invoking generic method with default datetime parameter through reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have simple generic method with following signature:

```
public static T SafeGetValue<T>(this XElement xElem, string attrName, 
                                 T defaultValue = default(T), bool throwExceptions = false)
```

Which I want to invoke like that:

```
var genericMethod = typeof(XElementExtensions).GetMethod("SafeGetValue");
genericMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
genericMethod.Invoke(null,new[] { xElem, "attr", Type.Missing, Type.Missing });
```

`type` variable is supplied and it is meant to be different for different invocations (typeof(int), typeof(bool), typeof(string) and etc.. ) , but when I supply it with `DateTime`, I got runtime exception:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.Additional information: Encountered an invalid type for a default value.

Comment: You are doing everything correctly. Unfortunately, this is a bug that Microsoft wouldn't fix.